# how to rearrange differential equation solution using matlab?

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I have an equation:

> dC(t)/dt = -K*C + G

I used MATLAB to solve this equation and I got this solution:

> C(t) = G/K + (Co-G/K)*exp(-K*t/V)

How can I rearrange this equation to get K=?

Comment: This is confusing. If you are solving a differential equation you are solving C (as it is the part that has the derivative) for a known K. If C and K are both unknown then you have an undetermined system of equations.

Comment: If the unknown is `K`, what are the knowns of this problems and in what form are they available?

Answer (score 2):

Because your equation has `K` inside and outside the exponential, you can't get a nice closed form solution, so the best you hope to achieve is a numerical approximation.

```
>> syms t C(t) K G C0
>> D=dsolve(diff(C)==-K*C+G,C(0)==C0) %// solve the ODE with an initial condition
D =
(G - exp(-K*t)*(G - C0*K))/K

%// Solve for k given particular values of the other variables
>> k=solve(subs(C(t)==D,{G,t,C,C0},{1,2,1,0.5}),K)
k =
0.91228212986814722960889983912519
```

If you ignore the initial condition, you can get an equation, but it is in terms of the Lambert W function, and is really not useful for anything.

```
>> syms t C(t) K G
>> D=dsolve(diff(C)==-K*C+G)
D =
(G - C2*exp(-K*t))/K

>> solve(C==D,K)
ans =
(G + (C(t)*lambertw(0, -(C2*t*exp(-(G*t)/C(t)))/C(t)))/t)/C(t)
```

Comment: Thanks David. It is a really big help. I've tried to solve the question numerically but don't know how to insert the values for the known Co, C, G and t.

Comment: by the way, i got this error when entering into Matlab2010a.

   ??? Undefined function or variable 't'.

Error in ==> try2 at 5
k=solve(subs(C(t)==D,{G,t,C,C0}',{1,2,1,0.5}),K)

Comment: 2010a is several versions old and the symbolic toolbox has changed quite a bit since then. In 2013b and later what I posted works, unfortunately I can't really help with pre-2013b Matlab as I don't have that installed. I edited my answer to include the intialisation of the symbolic variables, I hope that works. I don't know what to suggest if it doesn't.